# Paypal Express Checkout returning page has not Shipping address and no shipping method

Tags: paypal

When a client use `Paypal Express Checkout is redirected to Paypal page`, he is able to chose the shipping method, after he click on Continue is redirected to Review page with `blank shipping address and no shipping method` (Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with out of the box functionality. The Review page stays empty and I can't send the order off.

Comment: Same issue here. I've narrowed it down to that $address->getGroupedAllShippingRates() yields no results on first try. But when, after the confirmation page has fully loaded, I manually hit the paypal/express/return/ page again all works fine. Must be something related to the order in which things are being loaded...